# Filtering out rows based on an IQR score in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

```
df_boyd_out = df_boyd[~((df_boyd['MTTR'] < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) | (df_boyd['MTTR'] > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))).any(axis=1)]
```

The above is my code, which returns: `ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type Series`

I've tried:

```
df_boyd_out = df_boyd[~((df_boyd.MTTR < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) | (df_boyd.MTTR > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))).any(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `.any(axis=1)` since your code already returns a `Series` of boolean values.

Other point, you can replace:

```
~((df_boyd.MTTR < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) | (df_boyd.MTTR > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR)))
```

by:

```
df_boyd.MTTR.between(Q1 - 1.5 * IQR, Q3 + 1.5 * IQR)
```

which is probably more readable.